# How to create a local terminal profile?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code's settings, you can easily add custom terminal profiles like this:

```json
"terminal.integrated.profiles.linux": {
        "test": {
            "path": "bash",
            "icon": "terminal-bash",
        }
    }
```

This will open a terminal host for the host on which the vscode server is running (local, devcontainer, remote over ssh, etc).

With that said, VS Code is still capable of opening a local terminal on the host regardless of where it the server is running with the `workbench.action.terminal.newLocal` command:

[image: Opening VSCode local terminal]

Is it possible to write a terminal profile to open a local terminal from the usual UI?

[image: Screenshot of listed profiles]